# Deploy web app in different ports JETTY

Tags: java, jetty

How can I deploy a web app in two different ports (say port 8080 and 9999) in JETTY so that I will expose health checks, metrics and other administrative resources in one port (#9999) with limited number of threads and the rest of services in the main port (#8080). I am not using embedded server so I was looking for a solution that works for standalone deployment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to do it.

[Visit here to see the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/serving-webapp-from-particular-port.html)

Comment: This part of the documentation talks about configuring multiple servers. I couldn't find anything related with my use case.